# Parse a website RSS feed in XML

Tags: xml, parsing, hyperlink, feed

I have a link like www.google.com/feed, and I would like to parse this link in XML, to have www.mywebsite.com/feed.xml

How can I do it ? 
I'm new in XML's world, so if someone can give me a link who explain the method ...
Thanks :)

Comment: Your question not clear, what language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

For instance `XDocument.Load("http://www.mywebsite.com/feed.xml");` in C#